# how to find the "Remote Desktop Connection Broker" server in a Windows Server envrionment?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am about to setup the licensing for the Remote Desktop server and point it to the licensing server.  Problem is, I am not sure if this environment even has a connection broker server installed or do I need to install this on the RD host itself  There will only be 1 RD host and this is replacing one that has been decommissioned.
Is there a way to find out if this environment has this server from within the DC itself?
update: sorry - totally forgot -Windows 2012 R2

Comment: Things "are different" between Windows 2008 and Windows 2012+ in the world of RDS.  Both are tagged in the question, can you give a bit more background on what you think might be there vs. what you are attempting to deploy?

Comment: @Mike Kolah: I don't believe there are any use cases for a connection broker when there is only one remote desktop session host.  Are you asking about the broker or license server?

Answer (score 0):

This article gives some background:

[Troubleshooting TS Licensing Installation | Microsoft Docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771756(v=ws.10).aspx)

There is a SRV record type for TS licensing, which you should be able to leverage to help via NSLOOKUP.  My google-fu is weak today, I'm having trouble finding the SRV type.  It's similar to how you would discover a KMS licensing server on a network.

Also, for an environment where RDS/TS is integrated with Active Directory, there should be an AD group called Remote Desktop Licensing Servers, with component servers listed.  I'd imagine this would give you a pretty good idea of what is still out there.